# How to re-structure (select) data in SAS

Tags: select, data-structures, sas

I have a dataset like this:

```
    DATA HAVE;
        INPUT _USUBJID $ VISITNUM $ VISIT $ ;
    CARDS;
    01/01 VISIT1 SCREENING
    01/01 VISIT1 SCREENING
    01/01 VISIT1 SCREENING
    01/01 VISIT1 RETEST
    01/01 VISIT1 RETEST
    01/01 VISIT3 BASELINE2
    01/01 VISIT3 BASELINE2
    01/01 VISIT3 RETEST
    01/01 VISIT3 RETEST
    01/02 VISIT1 SCREENING
    01/02 VISIT1 SCREENING
    01/02 VISIT3 BASELINE2
    01/02 VISIT3 BASELINE2
    ;
    RUN;
```

I need to restructure it as:

```
    DATA WANT;
        INPUT _USUBJID $ VISITNUM $ VISIT $ ;
    CARDS;
    01/01 VISIT1 RETEST
    01/01 VISIT1 RETEST
    01/01 VISIT3 RETEST
    01/01 VISIT3 RETEST
    01/02 VISIT1 SCREENING
    01/02 VISIT1 SCREENING
    01/02 VISIT3 BASELINE2
    01/02 VISIT3 BASELINE2
    ;
    RUN;
```

If a subject has both SCREENING and RETEST values, I need to extract the RETEST values for that subject. If a subject does not have any RETEST values, then I only need the visit (i.e., SCREENING, or BASELINE2 in this example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in three stages:

1. Grab the retest _usubjid,visitnum pairs and associated values to one dataset (called retest below)
2. Get the no-retest _usubjid,visitnum pairs and associated value to another dataset by subtracting the retest pairs from the original pairs, and joining the values back in (called onetest below)
3. Concatenate retest and no-retest values.

Example of that in SQL:

```
proc sql;
    create table retest as 
        select *
        from have 
        where VISIT="RETEST";

    create table onetest as
        select * from
            ((select distinct _usubjid, visitnum 
            from have)
            except 
            (select distinct _usubjid, visitnum
            from retest)) as onetesters
            left join 
            have on 
                onetesters._usubjid = have._usubjid and 
                onetesters.visitnum = have.visitnum;

    create table want as 
        select * from retest 
        union all
        select * from onetest;
quit;
```